# Cross product of basis vectors in general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, vectors

Say I wanted to find an expression for the differential surface trapped between two basis vectors (in 4-dimensional curved coordinates), one approach would be to take their cross product, and take the absolute value of the resulting vector. But from what I understand, the cross product cannot work in 4 dimensions. In that case, in what way can the differential surface be calculated in general relativity, a theory that deals with 4-dimensional coordinates? Could one produce a tensor from the cross product of the basis vectors (just as the dot product of the basis vectors produces the metric tensor)? would it have any significant physical meaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parallelogram spanned by two vectors - and more generally the generalized volume spanned by $n$ vectors - is expressed by the [wedge product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra) of these vectors.

The cross product in three dimensions is the concatenation of the wedge product and the [Hodge dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator).